# #include <mutex> causes the bind() function call to throw errors at compile time, why?

Tags: c++, mutex

I haven't seen this issue before and wasn't exactly sure how to even search for a solution to this problem because i'm not sure what to even look for. I have some code using sockets to read/write to my linux device driver. This code is tested and works as is.

I would like to add a mutex to my program for thread safety reasons but as soon as I add `#include <mutex>` to my program's main.cpp file and ONLY that line the `<sys/socket.h> bind()` function throws an error at compile time...

Here is the line causing the problem once I `#include <mutex>` and change nothing else in my code

```
if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0)
```

> dp_comm.cpp: In function 'int setup_socket_to_dev(const char*, int*)':
>   dp_comm.cpp:160:64: error: no match for 'operator<' in
>   'std::bind(_Functor&&, _ArgTypes&& ...) [with _Functor = int&,
>   _ArgTypes = {sockaddr*, unsigned int}, typename std::_Bind_helper<_Functor, _ArgTypes>::type =
>   std::_Bind]((* &((sockaddr*)(& saddr))),
>   (* &20u)) < 0'

I also tried to create an int and have it equal the return value of `bind()`

```
int ret_bind = bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
```

> dp_comm.cpp: In function 'int setup_socket_to_dev(const char*, int*)':
>   dp_comm.cpp:160:71: error: cannot convert 'std::_Bind_helper::type {aka std::_Bind}' to 'int' in initialization

**Why does `#include <mutex>` cause my compiler to throw a fit at the `bind()` call?**

The only way the code will compile when I `#include <mutex>` is the following

```
bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
```

What's going on?

Comment: Do you have a `using namespace std;` in your code? `bind` is a name in that namespace but also probably a name in your socket implementation.

Comment: yes the code i'm editing does `using namespace std`

Comment: Well, the answer is simple - don't do that.

Comment: yeah, it's not my code, and it's basically one of those things where someone made some prototype and then it was never touched because it "worked" and I'm trying to add functionality to show proof of concept but also change little as possible. I will be refactoring it and I plan remove `using namespace std`

Comment: I nominated for reopen because the question is fundamentally different: answers to the linked duplicate do not answer this question or explain how to make the code work even if `using namespace std;` cannot be removed. (There may be _another_ question of which this is a duplicate, but in my opinion the linked duplicate is not it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have

```
using namespace std;
```

somewhere in your code, [which you shouldn't do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). The `bind()` socket function is being confused with [`std::bind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) which is defined in `<functonal>` (and which `<mutex>` may well include).

If you absolutely cannot remove `using namespace std;` then you can disambiguate to select the `bind()` function in the global namespace by prefixing it with `::`, i.e., `::bind(...)`.

Comment: the :: fixed it, i appreciate the quick answer and the explanation! makes sense